# Calling ashx service returns 500 internal server error even though service completes the business

Tags: c#, web-services, ashx

I am calling ashx service for creating users on third party, I have URL and query string parameters set. the request accepts POST/GET http methods, and the response should return response code and response text as xml.

The weird thing is the users are being created but the response throws an exception [500 Internal Server error].

Here is the Code:

```
string URI = "https://thirdpartyservice.com/ApiHandler.ashx?";
string params = "ptf_cmd=403&ptf_method=md5" +
            "&ptf_timer=" + sTimer +
            "&ptf_check=" + sCheck +
            "&ptf_client=" + rsaClient +
            "&ptf_partner=" + sPartner +
            "&ptf_offername=" + offername +
            "&ptf_host=" + rsaHost +
            "&ptf_login=" + sLogin +
            "&ptf_password=" + password +
            "&ptf_firstname=" + firstName +
            "&ptf_lastname=" + lastName +
            "&ptf_email=" + userEmail +
            "&ptf_interfacelanguage=" + rsaInterfaceLanguage +
            "&ptf_role=" + rsaUserRole +
            "&ptf_pupildiscipline=" + rsaPupilDiscipline +
            "&ptf_detailedResult=1" +
            "&ptf_endingurl=" + rsaReturnUrl +
            "&ptf_admingroup=" + rsaAdminGroup +
            "&ptf_pedagroup=" + rsaPedaGroup +
            "&ptf_usercreationmode=API";
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
                string xmlResult = wc.DownloadString(URI + params); //throws exception [500 Internal Server Error].
                //string xmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, params);//throws exception [500 Internal Server Error].
            }
```

I tried the request without setting the header and both POST/GET but also throws an exception.
Also I used HttpWebRequest class to send the request but it fails. Any suggestion(s) how to handle this?

Comment: The 500 Internal Server error means the error in happening in the service you are calling.  You need to check with who created the service to see what the error is.

Comment: It might not be your fault at all, or it could be the service is poorly handling things. Ideally you should never get a 500 error, they should handle all errors in a way that gives you some kind of usable response. Can you work with their support to troubleshoot?

Comment: @KenTucker, I talked to the technical from their side, and told me there are no errors found in their logs.

Comment: @Crowcoder, How comes the service is creating users [i am checking them on their portal] while response crashes. I talked to them and told me their services are running years ago!

Comment: Errors don't necessarily only happen before things like, creating users. Something could be breaking after, possibly their logging since they say they see no errors.